# Adds a dictionary value to another dictionary with out replacing the previous one

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to copy a dictionary value to another dictionary
I used the code

```
 [searchrequest addEntriesFromDictionary:productrequest];
```

So now the searchrequest contains what exacty the productrequest has.
After some point of time I need to add some values to the searchrequest with out overwritting the existing data

I read that "If both dictionaries contain the same key, the receiving dictionary’s previous value object for that key is sent a release message, and the new value object takes its place."

Is there any other solution for my problem?

Comment: You can't add two values for the same key ... Each key must has exactly one value ... You can add whatever you want with a different key

Comment: Seems simple enough -- don't add the new entry if there's already a matching one there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two of more objects for the same key, I think you should use NSMutableArray as your value.

When you want to add a new object to searchrequest, let's say the key is "myKey", the new object is newObj, you can use the code below:

```
NSMutableArray mArray = [searchrequest objectForKey:@"myKey"] ;
if (!mArray) {
    mArray = [NSMutableArray array] ;
    [searchrequest setObject:mArray forKey:@"myKey"] ;
}
[mArray addObject:newObj] ;
```